# Sendgrid parse webhook - email forwarding

Tags: php, sendgrid, email

I am having a PHP web application with SendGrid integration for both incoming (parse webhook) and outcoming mail (PHP `mail()` with system configuration for mail proxy). Currently our incoming mail system consists of an endpoint, which saves all contact emails to our database. We want also to have some direct email forwarding mappings to other mail providers (like ceo@mysite.com => my.address@example.com).

As far as I know, there is no routing of email or forwarding them with SMTP protocol in SendGrid's side, only plain API calls connecting to our endpoint. Creating MX records pointing to our IP address is not an option, as we don't want to reveal our servers' origin IP address to the public (DDoS risk).

Should I just write code to get the contents of email and `mail()` it forward? Some data will be missing, but for the most part it should work. Or is there a way to connect something like a Gmail Business account to listen for mails for these specific addresses?

Comment: Did you find the solution to your question? I have the same problem. sending emails only supports JSON, so even if I get raw payload from Sendgrid I can't use the same payload to send via Sendgrid, instead we have create a new JSON request and embed everything including attachments. Is there a better way?

Comment: @PouyaSanooei Haven't still found a good way to forward mails.

Comment: any updates on this in 2020?

Comment: consider using a third-party email forwarding service, you can offload the responsibility of email routing and forwarding, reducing the exposure of your server's IP address to potential DDoS attacks.

Answer (score -1):

There is not a straight forward workaround for that.

1. Use the SendGrid Parse Webhook to receive incoming emails.
2. Store the contact emails to your database (as you're doing)
3. Write a custom forwarding logic in your application. When an email arrives and if it matches one of the forwarding rules ceo@mysite.com to my.address@example.com)
   Use the PHP mail() function or an SMTP library to forward the email to your desired address (e.g., xyz@example.com)

> Note that some information, such as the original sender's IP address,
> may not be preserved in this process. Also use HTTPS to encrypt
> communication between your application and SendGrid's API to protect
> sensitive data.

4. You have to set up the forwarding rules within Gmail for specific addresses like ceo@mysite.com.com to forward emails to xyz@example.com. This is only possible in the Gmail Business settings.

> Note This forwarding is managed by Gmail not in your PHP application.
> This is an option if you're open to using Gmail for this purpose.

5. To avoid showing your server's origin IP address, You may user services like Cloudflare or a similar CDN/WAF. These services act as a proxy between your server and the public, masking your server's real IP address.

Remember to Implement additional security measures based on your specific application and threat model.